# OpenWRT: Reset iptables to default settings

Tags: iptables, openwrt

I somehow cleared all my `iptables` rules by accident (details below). In the Web-Access, all settings under "Network->Firewall" are now empty, except for some lines in "Custom Rules" that I had added.

Is there some way to reset *only* the iptables rules to factory defaults? I have many additional things setup in the router, which is why I would like to avoid having to reset the whole device/OpenWRT, as it would be a lot of work to reset all that.

I can currently no longer access the internet through the router. Strangely enough, I can still SSH into the device from the local network and also access the Web-Access, which I would have thought would not work anymore.

**Additional information:**

This happened when I was setting up iptables to for OpenVPN following these instructions:

https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53

I added these rules from SSH console and pressed "Apply" in the Web-Access (at the top right). After this, everything worked as expected. Unfortunately in a moment of dimness, I today pressed "Save and Apply" in the Web-Access when I wanted to added the iptables-rules from the link to my custom rules. For some reason, this caused the whole iptables to be cleared (as described above) and I can now no longer access the internet through that router.

I am using OpenWRT version: BARRIER BREAKER (14.07, r42625).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to restore my firewall settings by getting the corresponding settings file directly from the OpenWRT GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/tree/5ce38c486c525b28d9784f83e839537aa0149123/package/network/config/firewall/files).

The file that I needed was `firewall.config`. I moved this file to the file `/etc/config/firewall` on the router using SCP (I made a backup of the current one). After restarting the router the settings in the Web-Access under `Network -> Firewall` were restored to the defaults and my internet-access was working again.